# Getting the system's time zone with Dragon NaturallySpeaking's Advanced Scripting

Tags: timezone, naturallyspeaking

I want to display the current date and time with Dragon NaturallySpeaking's Advanced Scripting:

I display the date and the time as follows:

```
Sub Main
    DateToday$ = Format(Now,"yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss")
    SendKeys DateToday$
End Sub
```

It outputs something like "2015-01-19 21:45:07".

How can I write the system's time zone as well?

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Comment: Since this question received no answer, I posted it on Quora:  https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-can-I-get-the-systems-time-zone-with-Dragon-NaturallySpeakings-Advanced-Scripting

Answer (score 0):

Well, see my answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44507647/5521857

So, have Dragon get it by calling another script (autohotkey does it, and use shellexecute with the 6 at the end so it runs minimized) that copies it to the clipboard, and then have Dragon assign the clipboard to a variable and use it.  Remember to add a wait, though to make sure the clipboard is populates.