# How can I insert the CD-ROM drive with Dragon NaturallySpeaking's advanced scripting?

Tags: cd-rom, naturallyspeaking

Is there any way to insert the CD-ROM drive with Dragon NaturallySpeaking's advanced scripting?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I'm sensing a theme here . . .

Like I said, whenever you need to, just use some other utility.  You can carry around a single autohotkey megascript that runs off a USB to give you your favorite hotkeys and hot strings while also letting you call individual subroutines by passing along command line parameters.

Anyway, the complete technique is described here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44507647/5521857

But note my answer re the time zones info and using clipboard for returning that info back to the Dragon script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44526303/5521857

Hth,