# How can I mute the speakers with Dragon NaturallySpeaking's advanced scripting?

Tags: windows, audio, naturallyspeaking

Is there any way to mute the speakers with Dragon NaturallySpeaking's advanced scripting?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want done can be done with any other scripting language, use it and call that script from Dragon.

DNS and DP Advanced Scripting is generations old.  I use AutoHotKey for nearly everything, but I have a few VBS and JS scripts I call, and even an HTA.  E.g., I have an AHK script that manipulates my soundcards changes volume, mutes, etc., all by passing arguments in from the command line:

```
Sub Main
' Command is called "<Volume>" and that list includes: 
'   mute Mike, mute the Mike, show the volume, show volume, toggle the volume, 
'   toggle volume, volume, volume down, volume down three, volume down two,
'   volume loud, volume mute, volume off, volume up, volume up loud, 
'   volume up three, volume up two.

x = ListVar1  
If InStr(x," the ") Then x = Mid$(x, 1, InStr(x," the ")) + Mid$(x, InStr(x," the ")+5)
If x = "mute Mike" Then ShellExecute "pgVolume.ahk mutemic", 6
If x = "show volume" Then ShellExecute "pgVolume.ahk showvol", 6
If x = "toggle volume" Then ShellExecute "pgVolume.ahk togglevol", 6

x = Mid$(ListVar1, 8)
If x = "down" Then ShellExecute "pgVolume.ahk down 1", 6
If x = "down three" Then ShellExecute "pgVolume.ahk down 3", 6
If x = "down two" Then ShellExecute "pgVolume.ahk down 2", 6
If x = "loud" Then ShellExecute "pgVolume.ahk up 6", 6
If x = "mute" Then ShellExecute "pgVolume.ahk down 6", 6
If x = "off" Then ShellExecute "pgVolume.ahk down 6", 6
If x = "up" Then ShellExecute "pgVolume.ahk up 1", 6
If x = "up loud" Then ShellExecute "pgVolume.ahk up 6", 6
If x = "up three" Then ShellExecute "pgVolume.ahk up 3", 6
If x = "up two" Then ShellExecute "pgVolume.ahk up 2", 6
End Sub
```

My AHK script includes subroutines and a reference to VA.AHK (VA v2.2 at http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/21984-/ ).

Hth,